# Why is it impossible to instantiate a data structure due to "overflow while adding drop-check rules"?

Tags: data-structures, rust, recursive-type

Here is a data structure I can write down and which is accepted by the Rust compiler:

```
pub struct Pair<S, T>(S, T);

pub enum List<T> {
    Nil,
    Cons(T, Box<List<Pair<i32, T>>>),
}
```

However, I cannot write

```
let x: List<i32> = List::Nil;
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9aaed9de6daa5b81035ce1604c543eb4&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

as Rust will complain about an "overflow while adding drop-check rules".
Why shouldn't it be possible to instantiate `List::Nil`?

It should be noted that the following works:

```
pub struct Pair<S, T>(S, T);

pub enum List<T> {
    Nil,
    Cons(T, Box<List<T>>),
}

fn main() {
    let x: List<i32> = List::Nil;
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=386f4fbd79abce89fb6a1081e670d13b&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: I don't know enough about the compiler to explain why this is causing an infinite loop, but an aside: you should read [*'Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists'*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/) if you haven't already! Linked lists are deceptively tricky to get right in Rust.

Comment: What’s the meaning of the pair? `Box<List<Pair<i32, T>>>` seems like a weird type in `Cons`.

Comment: @JoeClay thanks, I'm still at the beginning stages of learning Rust, so this'll help a lot

Comment: @Ry- This is just a simplified example. I tried to port Haskell's [FingerTrees](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fingertree) and see how far I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the type hasn't been instantiated, the compiler is mostly worried about the *size* of the type being constant and known at compile-time so it can be placed on the stack. The Rust compiler will complain if the type is infinite, and *quite often* a `Box` will fix that by creating a level of indirection to a child node, which is also of known size because it boxes its own child too.

This won't work for your type though.

When you instantiate `List<T>`, the type of the second argument of the `Cons` variant is:

```
Box<List<Pair<i32, T>>>
```

Notice that the inner `List` has a type argument `Pair<i32, T>`, not `T`.

That inner list also has a `Cons`, whose second argument has type:

```
Box<List<Pair<i32, Pair<i32, T>>>>
```

Which has a `Cons`, whose second argument has type:

```
Box<List<Pair<i32, Pair<i32, Pair<i32, T>>>>>
```

And so on.

Now this doesn't exactly explain why you can't use this type. The size of the type will increase linearly with how deeply it is within the `List` structure. When the list is short (or empty) it doesn't reference any complex types.

Based on the error text, the reason for the overflow is related to drop-checking. The compiler is checking that the type is dropped correctly, and if it comes across another type in the process it will check if *that* type is dropped correctly too. The problem is that each successive `Cons` contains a completely new type, which gets bigger the deeper you go, and the compiler has to check if each of these will be dropped correctly. The process will never end.

Comment: So basically Rust will compute a (possibly cyclic) dependency graph of types? And I suppose if the graph grows too large, the compiler will complain. Is this due to the implementation of rustc or can this behaviour change in the future?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c176d2f2ef3608a412ce48c57ed8a930&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015
It gives the same error. `size_of<T> == size_of<Pair<T>>`

Comment: @aSpex Yes, see the explanation at the end that I edited in after. It's not related to the size of the type in bytes, but the relative space required to describe it.